# How to remove unnecessary VsCode terminals

Tags: visual-studio-code

JavaScript Debug Terminal does something in the terminal dropdown.

How can I remove it from the dropdown list?
(I'm using python, I ran VsCode in a container with ONLY python. I don't understand where it came from)

[image]

Comment: Activate it, then click the trash icon.

Comment: Activated, clicked on the trash can icon - it just closed, but did not disappear from the drop-down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "JavaScript Debug Terminal": null,
    "zsh": null
}
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/135791